# Cannot Install a software from software center in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-center

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have also created an ubuntu Single sign on account.

But I cannot install anything from **Ubuntu software center**. The install button is not there. All I can see is a disabled `Use this source` button.

Comment: Can you add a Screenshot so I can get a better idea as to what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

First, go into software sources and check what is enabled and basically enable everything that is there so long as you made no modifications, then go to a terminal and run sudo apt-get update to make sure you have the latest software list

Answer (score 0):

Purge and reinstall the software-center:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove software-center && sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Then reboot.

Comment: I tried it. Now my Software center is uninstalled.
but it not getting installed.
Its showing this error.

Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Hi,
This is what worked for me.
1.sudo apt-get --purge autoremove software-center
2.sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install synaptic